# How to remove POWERED BY TINY from TinyMce web component editor

Tags: tinymce

I am using TinyMce web component editor, i have put my API key as well. But still getting branding "POWERED BY TINY".

Code as below:-

```
<tinymce-editor branding="false" id="editor" height="150" resize="false" menubar="false">
                      This will be the initial content of the editor
</tinymce-editor>
```

branding ="false" also not working.

Answer (score 2):

Via init() function:

```
        tinymce.init({
...
            statusbar: 'false',
...
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just so you're aware removing the branding is a [paid feature of TinyMCE](https://about.tiny.cloud/legal/attribution-requirements/).

The branding setting of TinyMCE is not one of the built-in attributes that the webcomponent supports but as with any attribute you can still set it via the escape hatch of declaring a object globally in Javascript and then referencing the name.

```html
<script>window.myConfig = { branding: false };</script>
<tinymce-editor id="editor" height="150" resize="false" menubar="false" config="myConfig">
This will be the initial content of the editor
</tinymce-editor>
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/webcomponent/#settingadditionalconfigurationoptions

Comment: Thanks for replying James. 
But i am using this editor in stencil component. and this component will be use some where else.
So, how i can add this <script>window.myConfig = { branding: false };</script> inside component.

Comment: my file look like below

`import { Component, Host } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'cb-tn-sw-divider-component',
  styleUrl: 'divider-component.scss',
  shadow: true,
})
export class DividerComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <div id="editor-container">
        <tinymce-editor >
            This will be the initial content of the editor
        </tinymce-editor>
        <span class="content-count">Word count: 50</span>
        </div>
      </Host>
    );
  }
}`

Comment: I do not know anything about stencil components so I can't comment on that. If it does turn out to be impossible then I suggest you open a support case with Tiny which should be possible with a paid subscription.

Comment: For stenciljs: Try adding it in componentDidLoad. (window as any).myConfig = { branding: false };

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions above or equal 5 use `branding: false,` in the following manner

```
 tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea',
forced_root_block : ' ',
branding: false,
)};
```